# How to change default project build options?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

[image]

How I could change this option to default: release x64?

I have my source on a folder and i have it as Release x64, but when i make a copy of this folder and open the project from this copied folder its set to Debug Win32.

Do someone know in what file the current option I'm using is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `MachineX64(/MACHINE:X64)` in `Properties->Linker->Advanced->Target Machine`. Apply it and select `x64`. Then, the default platform is x64 next time you open.
[image]

Also, if you want to permanently change the default platform, you could replace `Win32` with `x64` in the following three files.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> tudio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCWizards default.vcxproj, DefaultTest.vcxproj, vcupgradedefault.vcxproj

Then, when you create a new project, the debug paltform is only x64.

When you use `Win32`, the files generated after debugging are saved in the `Debug` folder under the project directory